# ModelForm in Django with One-to-One relationship: unable to update

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django's ModelForm functionality to create a form. However, my particular Model is extended with another model using a one-to-one relationship. I therefore create two separate forms and they are filled out by the user and then submitted. This all works 100% when *creating* a record (both the place and restaurant record are created), but not when *updating* a record. When I try to update a form, it does not pass the is_valid check for the restaurant form.

I am new to Django and must also say that there seems to be quite some repetition in this code. Is there a better way to update/insert records with less repetition?

My models:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class PlaceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = ['name']

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(
        Place,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='restaurant',
        primary_key=True,
    )
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

class RestaurantForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        exclude = ['place']
```

And here is my view:

```
def create_or_edit(request, id=False):
    restaurantform = False
    if id:
        info = get_object_or_404(Place, pk=id)
        form = PlaceForm(instance=info)
        if hasattr(info, 'restaurant'):
            restaurantform = RestaurantForm(instance=info.restaurant)
    else:
        info = False
        form = PlaceForm()
        if type == 'restaurant':
            restaurantform = RestaurantForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not id:
            form = PlaceForm(request.POST)
            if type == 'restaurant':
                restaurantform = RestaurantForm(request.POST)
        else:
            form = PlaceForm(request.POST, instance=info)
            if type == 'restaurant':
                restaurantform = RestaurantForm(request.POST, instance=info.restaurant)
        if form.is_valid() and restaurantform.is_valid():
            info = form.save(commit=False)
            info.site = request.site
            info.save()

            if type == 'restaurant':
                if id:
                    restaurantform.save()
                else:
                    restaurant = restaurantform.save(commit=False)
                    restaurant.place = info
                    restaurant.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Information was saved.')
            return redirect(reverse('app:record', args=[info.id]))
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Problem saving record')
```

Comment: What sets `type`?

Comment: Thanks @schillingt that was actually indeed the problem!! Type was only set when creating the record, not when updating it. The problem was solved!!

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you are accepting only post request "request.method == 'POST'" for creation. To update, write

if request.method == 'UPDATE' or 'PUT'
    write code here
    .........
    .........